# Can my laptop run Minecraft Shaders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-shader

I have an HP EliteBook 840 G2 It looks like this:

[image]

Here are the specs:

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz. Its maximum is 3.10GHz

GPU: Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500

RAM: 8.0 GB DDR3
I want to run Minecraft shaders because I like the look of it. But I am not sure if it will run on my PC because it is getting old and fragile. Also, I am not sure if this hardware would run Minecraft shaders whether new or not. Can someone please let me know if this laptop can run Minecraft shaders

Comment: @aytimothy Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're okay with 5 fps, no. You must at least have a dedicated GPU